# org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using struts and hibernate. I have a parent and child relation using set in hbm.
In the action I am using `session.saveOrUpdate()` method to save but while saving it is showing the below error. Can anyone help regardng this with explanation where I made the mistake?

Here is my hbm.file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

 <class name="com.model.cargo" table="cargo">
  <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
   <generator class="increment" />
  </id>
  <property name="cname" column="cname" />
  <property name="cdate" column="cdate" />
  <property name="csource" column="csource" />
  <property name="cdestination" column="cdestination" />
  <property name="create" column="createby" />
  <property name="status" column="status" />

  <set name="itemList" table="item" inverse="true"
   cascade="all-delete-orphan">
   <key>
    <column name="id" />
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="com.model.Item" />
  </set>
 </class>

 <class name="com.model.Item" table="item">
  <id name="itemid" column="itemid" type="java.lang.Long">
   <generator class="increment" />
  </id>
  <property name="itemName" column="itemname" />
  <property name="weight" column="weight" />
  <many-to-one class="com.model.cargo" name="cargo"
   column="id" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My action

```
package com.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import com.plugin.HibernatePlugIn;
import com.form.cargoForm;
import com.model.cargo;
import com.model.Item;


public class CargoAction extends DispatchAction {


 public ActionForward add(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {

  if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("Entering Master add method");
  }

  try {

   cargoForm cargoForm = (cargoForm) form;
   //System.out.println("ID" + cargoForm.getId());
   cargo cargo = new cargo();
   System.out.println("in cargo Action");
   // copy customerform to model
   cargoForm.reset(mapping, request);
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(cargo, cargoForm);
   cargoForm.reset(mapping, request);
  // cargoForm.setInputParam("new");
   // updateFormBean(mapping, request, cargoForm);

  }

  catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   return mapping.findForward("failure");
  }

  return mapping.findForward("success1");
 }

 public ActionForward save(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {

  SessionFactory sessionFactory=null;
  Session session =null;
  System.out.println("in cargo Action");
  try{
  sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) servlet
    .getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernatePlugIn.KEY_NAME);  
  session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

  cargoForm carForm = (cargoForm) form;


  cargo cargo = new cargo();

  System.out.println("in cargo Action");

  BeanUtils.copyProperties(cargo,carForm);
  System.out.println("id"+ carForm.getId()); 
  System.out.println("item id"+ carForm.getItemid()); 
  Set itemset = carForm.getItemDtl();

    System.out.println("size"+itemset.size()); 
    Iterator iterator =itemset.iterator();   
    while(iterator.hasNext()) { 
     Item it = (Item)iterator.next();
    System.out.println("name"+it.getItemName()); //log.debug("HERE");
   it.setCargo(cargo); } 

  cargo.setItemList(itemset);
  System.out.println("size"+ itemset.size()); 
  session.saveOrUpdate("cargo",cargo);
  tx.commit();
  }catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return mapping.findForward("success");

 }

 public ActionForward search(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {
  System.out.println("in cargo search Action");
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) servlet
    .getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernatePlugIn.KEY_NAME);
  HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  cargoForm cargoform = (cargoForm) form;
  // System.out.println("Name"+cargoForm.getName());
  cargo cargo = new cargo();
  System.out.println("in cargo search Action");
  // copy customerform to model
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(cargo, cargoform);
  String name;
  String status;
  String createby;

  name = cargo.getCname();
  status = cargo.getStatus();
  createby = cargo.getCreate();
  System.out.println("Name..." + name);
  System.out.println("status..." + status);
  System.out.println("createby..." + createby);
  try {
   if ((name.equals("")) && (createby.equals(""))
     && (status.equals("")))
    return mapping.findForward("failure");
   String SQL_QUERY = "from cargo c where c.cname=:name or c.status=:status or c.create=:createby";
   Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
   query.setParameter("name", name);
   query.setParameter("status", status);
   query.setParameter("createby", createby);
   ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
   for (Iterator i = query.iterate(); i.hasNext();) {
    cargo cargo1 = (cargo) i.next();
    al.add(cargo1);
    System.out.println("Cargo ID is:" + cargo1.getId());
   }
   System.out.println("Cargo list is:" + al.size());
   session1.setAttribute("clist", al);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return mapping.findForward("failure");
  }
  System.out.println("search Cargo list is success");

  return mapping.findForward("success");
 }




 public ActionForward edit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {
  SessionFactory sessionFactory=null;
  Session session =null;
  if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("Entering Master Edit method");
  }

  try {
   sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) servlet
     .getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernatePlugIn.KEY_NAME);
   session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
   cargoForm carForm = (cargoForm) form;
   // System.out.println(carForm.getStatus());
   // System.out.println(carForm.getCreate());
   cargo cargo = new cargo();
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(cargo, carForm);
      System.out.println("In Cargo Edit "+cargo.getId());
      String qstring = "from cargo c where c.id=:id";
   Query query = session.createQuery(qstring);
   query.setParameter("id", cargo.getId());
   ArrayList all = new ArrayList();
   cargo c = (cargo) query.iterate().next();

   System.out.println("Edit Cargo list " + all.size()); 


     Set purchaseArray = new HashSet();
           System.out.println("Edit"+c.getItemList().size());
           carForm.setItemDtl(purchaseArray);
           BeanUtils.copyProperties(carForm,c);
           // transaction.commit();
            session.flush();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return mapping.findForward("failure");
  }

  // return a forward to edit forward
  System.out.println("Edit Cargo list is success");
  return mapping.findForward("succ");
 }

 public ActionForward delete(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws Exception {

  try {
   SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) servlet
     .getServletContext().getAttribute(HibernatePlugIn.KEY_NAME);
   Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   cargoForm carForm = (cargoForm) form;
   // System.out.println(carForm.getStatus());
   // System.out.println(carForm.getCreate());
   cargo cargo = new cargo();
   BeanUtils.copyProperties(cargo, carForm);
      System.out.println("In Cargo Delete "+cargo.getId());
   //String qstring = "delete from cargo c where c.id=:id";
   //Query query = session.createQuery(qstring);
   session.delete("cargo",cargo);
     // session.delete(cargo);
     // session.flush();
   //query.setParameter("id", cargo.getId());
   //int row=query.executeUpdate();
   //System.out.println("deleted row"+row);
   tx.commit();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return mapping.findForward("failure");
  }
  // return a forward to edit forward
  System.out.println("Deleted success");
  return mapping.findForward("succes");
 }

}
```

My parent model

```
package com.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class cargo {

 private Long id;
 private String cname;
 private String cdate;
 private String csource;
 private String cdestination;
 private String create;
 private String status;

 private Set itemList = new HashSet();

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getCname() {
  return cname;
 }

 public void setCname(String cname) {
  this.cname = cname;
 }

 public String getCdate() {
  return cdate;
 }

 public void setCdate(String cdate) {
  this.cdate = cdate;
 }

 public String getCsource() {
  return csource;
 }

 public void setCsource(String csource) {
  this.csource = csource;
 }

 public String getCdestination() {
  return cdestination;
 }

 public void setCdestination(String cdestination) {
  this.cdestination = cdestination;
 }

 public String getCreate() {
  return create;
 }

 public void setCreate(String create) {
  this.create = create;
 }

 public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
 }

 public Set getItemList() {
  return itemList;
 }

 public void setItemList(Set itemList) {
  this.itemList = itemList;
 }


}
```

My child model

```
package com.model;

public class Item{

 private Long itemid;
 private String itemName;
 private String weight;
 private cargo cargo;

 public Long getItemid() {
  return itemid;
 }
 public void setItemid(Long itemid) {
  this.itemid = itemid;
 }
 public String getItemName() {
  return itemName;
 }
 public void setItemName(String itemName) {
  this.itemName = itemName;
 }
 public String getWeight() {
  return weight;
 }
 public void setWeight(String weight) {
  this.weight = weight;
 }
 public cargo getCargo() {
  return cargo;
 }
 public void setCargo(cargo cargo) {
  this.cargo = cargo;
 }


}
```

And my form

```
package com.form;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.model.Item;

public class cargoForm extends ActionForm {
 private Long id;
 private String cname;
 private String cdate;
 private String csource;
 private String cdestination;
 private String create;
 private String status;

 private Long[] itemid;
 private String[] itemName;
 private String[] weight;

 private Set itemset = new HashSet();

 public Long getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getCname() {
  return cname;
 }

 public void setCname(String cname) {
  this.cname = cname;
 }

 public String getCdate() {
  return cdate;
 }

 public void setCdate(String cdate) {
  this.cdate = cdate;
 }

 public String getCsource() {
  return csource;
 }

 public void setCsource(String csource) {
  this.csource = csource;
 }

 public String getCdestination() {
  return cdestination;
 }

 public void setCdestination(String cdestination) {
  this.cdestination = cdestination;
 }

 public String getCreate() {
  return create;
 }

 public void setCreate(String create) {
  this.create = create;
 }

 public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }

 public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
 }

 public Long[] getItemid() {
  return itemid;
 }

 public void setItemid(Long[] itemid) {
  this.itemid = itemid;
 }

 public String[] getItemName() {
  return itemName;
 }

 public void setItemName(String[] itemName) {
  this.itemName = itemName;
 }

 public String[] getWeight() {
  return weight;
 }

 public void setWeight(String[] weight) {
  this.weight = weight;
 }

 /*
  * public Set getItemset() { return itemset; }
  * 
  * public void setItemset(Set itemset) { this.itemset = itemset; }
  */
 public Set getItemDtl() {
  if (itemid != null) {
   itemset = new HashSet();
   System.out.println("cargadd form" + itemid);
   for (int i = 0; i < itemid.length; i++) {
    Item it = new Item();
    // it.setItemId(itemId[i]);
    it.setItemName(itemName[i]);
    System.out.println("cargadd form" + itemName[i]);
    it.setWeight(weight[i]);

    itemset.add(it);
    System.out.println("cargadd form" + itemset.size());
   }
  }
  return itemset;
 }

 public void setItemDtl(Set itemset) {
  System.out.println("cargadd form" + itemset.size());
  this.itemset = itemset;
  System.out.println("cargadd form" + itemset.size());
 }

 public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {

  cname = "";
  csource = "";
  cdestination = "";
  cdate = "";
  status = "";
  create = "";

 }

}
```

The error:

```
Hibernate: select max(itemid) from item
Hibernate: insert into item (itemname, weight, position, id, itemid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update cargo set name=?, date=?, source=?, destination=?, createby=?, status=? where id=?
Oct 4, 2010 10:44:08 AM org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher doExecuteBatch
SEVERE: Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:68)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
 at com.action.CargoAction.save(CargoAction.java:125)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Oct 4, 2010 10:44:08 AM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:68)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
 at com.action.CargoAction.save(CargoAction.java:125)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:46)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:68)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
 at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
 at com.action.CargoAction.save(CargoAction.java:125)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
 at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
 at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 47):

In the Hibernate mapping file for the `id` property, if you use any generator class, for that property you should not set the value explicitly by using a setter method.

If you set the value of the Id property explicitly, it will lead the error above. Check this to avoid this error.

Comment: First in userCredentials.hbm.xml file I used                      <id name="userId" column="UserId">
   <generator class="identity"></generator>
</id>                                                               After wrote below one the problem is resolved.                        <id name="userId" column="UserId"></id>

Comment: If you set the ID using a sequence, then DbUnit won't do it. Please correct me if I'm wrong I've yet to see DbUnit's support for sequences.

Answer (score 16):

its happen when you try to delete the same object and then again update the same object
use this after delete

```
session.clear();
```

Answer (score 4):

what i have experienced is that this exception raise when updating object have an id which  not exist in table. if you read exception message it says "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1" which means it was unable to found record with your given id.

To avoid this i always read record with same id if i found record back then i call update otherwise throw "exception record not found".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, `cargo` can have one or more `item`.  Each item would have a reference to its corresponding `cargo`.

From the log, `item` object is *inserted* first and then an attempt is made to *update* the `cargo` object (which does not exist).

I guess what you actually want is `cargo` object to be created first and then the `item` object to be created with the *id* of the cargo object as the reference - so, essentally re-look at the *save*() method in the *Action* class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, when you try to delete the same object and then again update the same object, then it gives you this error. As after every update hibernate for safe checking fires how many rows were updated, but during the code the data must have been deleted. Over here hibernate distinguish between the objects based on the key what u have assigned or the equals method.

so, just go through once through your code for this check, or try with implementing equals & hashcode method correctly which might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
* Thrown when a version number or timestamp check failed, indicating that the
* Session contained stale data (when using long transactions with versioning). 
* Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that does not exist.
*
*/

if ( expectedRowCount > rowCount ) {
   throw new StaleStateException(           
  "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [" + batchPosition +"]; actual row count: " + rowCount +"; expected: " + expectedRowCount);
   }
```

`<property name="show_sql">true</property>`
 This should show you the SQL that is executed and causes the problem.

*The StaleStateException would be thrown only after we successfully deleted one object, and then tried to delete another. The reason for this is, while persisting the  objects across sessions, objects must first be deleted from the Session before deleted. Otherwise, subsequent deletes will cause the  `StaleStateException` to be  thrown.

```
 Session.Remove(obj); 
 objectDAO.Delete(obj);
```

*The problem was that a table must have only one field that is primary key (I had a composite key and this is not a good idea, except for the many to many relation). I  have solved using a new id table field auto incremental.

*It can be fix by using `Hibernate session.update()` -- you need to have the table/view's primary key equal your corresponding bean property (eg. id).

*

Comment: This is a poorly written answer, could you try and be a bit clearer?

Answer (score 1):

This often happens when SQL statements are implemented in some performance costly way (implicit type conversions etc.).

I advice to debug the resulting SQL statements.

#### To debug turn on SQL logging

Turn on hibernate SQL logging by adding the following lines to your log4j properties file:

```
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

Before failing you will see the last SQL statement attempted in your log, copy and paste this SQL into an external SQL client and run it.

Comment: You should check [answer] for good advices on how to present your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

For `update()` and `saveOrUpdate()` methods, `id` generator value should be there in the database. For the `save()` method, `id` generator is not required.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, be sure that you don't set any id fields which are supposed to be auto-generated.

To cause this problem during testing, make sure that the db 'sees' aka flush this SQL, otherwise everything may seem fine when really its not.

I encountered this problem when inserting my parent with a child into the db:

1. Insert parent (with manual ID)
2. Insert child (with autogenerated ID)
3. Update foreign key in Child table to parent.

The 3. statement failed. Indeed the entry with the autogenerated ID (by Hibernate) was not in the table as a trigger changed the ID upon each insertion, thus letting the update fail with no matching row found.

Since the table can be updated without any Hibernate I added a check whether the ID is null and only fill it in then to the trigger.

Comment: Thanks ! I was strugling with this issue and looking at your answer I've found a solution. I had a trigger that was always setting a new identifier. Replaced the trigger code sothat the new identifier is set only if there's no identifier before insert. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same as well.Making the Id (0) doing "(your Model value).setId(0)" solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

*please do not set id of child class which is generator class is foreign only set parent class id if your parent class id is assigned...
just do one thing dont set id of child class via setter method your problem will be fix.....definately*.

Comment: You might want to add punctuation, your answer currently is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

So For my case I noticed hibernate is trying to update the record rather than inserting it and that thrown the exception mentioned.

I finally came to find that my entity had an updatedAt timestamp column:

```
<timestamp name="updatedDate" column="updated_date" />
```

and when I was trying to initialize the object i found that the code was 
setting this field explicitly.

after removing that setUpdateDate(new Date()) it worked and did an insert instead.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, another way this exception can occur is if:

- Your transaction isolation is `READ_COMMITTED`
- Transaction #1 queries for an entity, then deletes that entity
- A simultaneous transaction #2 does the same thing

Then this can happen: TX #1 successfully commits before TX #2, then when TX #2 tries to delete the entity (again) it's not there any more - even though it was found by a query earlier in that same transaction. Note this anomaly is allowed with `READ_COMMITTED` isolation.

In my case the resulting exception looked like this:

```
HHH000315: Exception executing batch [org.hibernate.StaleStateException:
  Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
  count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from Foobar where id=?],
  SQL: delete from Foobar where id=?
```

Answer (score -2):

if The given id is not exist in the DB ,then you may get this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```