# Hibernate Delete Error: Batch Update Returned Unexpected Row Count

Tags: java, hibernate, methods, dao

I wrote this method below that is suppose to delete a member record from the database. But when I use it in my servlet it returns an error.

**MemberDao Class**

```
public static void deleteMember(Member member) {
    Session hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
    hibernateSession.delete(member);
    tx.commit();
}
```

**Controller Part**

```
if(delete != null) {
    HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
    Member member = (Member) httpSession.getAttribute("member");

    MemberDao.deleteMember(member);

    nextPage = "ledenlijst.jsp";
}
```

**HTTP Status 500**

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Sometimes it even throws this error when I try to execute the page multiple times.

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Does anybody know what exactly is causing these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853106/org-hibernate-stalestateexception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-fr

Comment: Do you try to delete the same `member` twice?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The error can be caused by several things. I'm not taking the credit for it, found it [here](http://java-fp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/orghibernatestalestateexception-batch.html).

> 1. Flushing the data before committing the object may lead to clear all
>      object pending for persist.
> 2. If object has primary key which is auto generated and you are
>      forcing an assigned key
> 3. if you are cleaning the object before committing the object to
>      database.
> 4. Zero or Incorrect ID: If you set the ID to zero or something else,
>      Hibernate will try to update instead of insert.
> 5. Object is Stale: Hibernate caches objects from the session. If the
>      object was modified, and Hibernate doesn’t know about it, it will
>      throw this exception — note the StaleStateException

Also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2743663/1993019) by [beny23](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227140/beny23) which gives a few further hints to find the problem.

> - In your hibernate configuration, set hibernate.show_sql to true. This should show you the SQL that is executed and causes the problem.
> - Set the log levels for Spring and Hibernate to DEBUG, again this will give you a better idea as to which line causes the problem.
> - Create a unit test which replicates the problem without configuring a transaction manager in Spring. This should give you a better idea of the offending line of code.

Comment: Object is Stale: Hibernate caches objects from the session. If the object was modified, and Hibernate doesn’t know about it, it will throw this exception — note the StaleStateException

Answer (score 4):

The exception 
`org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`
use to be thrown when Hibernate notice that the entity he wants to flush to the database isn't exactly as it was at the beginning of the transaction.

I described more in details two different use cases that happen to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743130/hibernate-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-0-actual-row/46989666#46989666).

Answer (score 1):

In my case this exception was caused by wrong entity mapping. There were no cascade for relation, and referenced child entity wasn't saved before trying to reference it from parent. Changing it to

```
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

fixed the issue.

Surely best way to find cause of this exception is setting show_sql and DEBUG level for logs - it will stop just at the sql that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.
The code was working in the testing environment. But it was not working in staging environment.

```
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 3; expected: 1
```

The problem was the table had single entry for each primary key in testing DB table. But in staging DB there was multiple entry for same primary key. ( Problem is in staging DB the table didn't had any primary key constraints also there was multiple entry.)

So every time on update operation it gets failed. It tries to update single record and expect to get update count as 1. But since there was 3 records in the table for the same primary key, The result update count finds 3. Since expected update count and actual result update count didn't match, It throws exception and rolls back.

After the I removed all the records which have duplicate primary key and added primary key constraints. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for my case, maybe it will help you!

Actually it was a conversion problem between a database field type (timestamp on postgreSQL) and his equivalent property type (Calendar) on hibernate xml file.
When Hibernate did this update request, it didn't retrieve the row because the request interrogate with a bad convert Calendar value.
So I simply replaced property type "Calendar" in "Date" in Hibernate xml file and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i recently experienced this and what happened was that i used the update method and it was throwing an exception because there was no existing record. I changed the method to saveOrUpdate. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue with hibernate/JPA 2.1 when using memcached as the secondary cache. You would get the above exception along with a StaleStateException. The resolution was different than what has been noted previously.

I noticed that if you have an operation that interleaves deletes and selects (finds) from within the same table and transaction, hibernate can become overwhelmed and report that stale state exception. It would only occur for us during production as multiple identical operations on different entities would occur on the same table. You would see the system timeout and toss exceptions.

The solution is to simply be more efficient. Rather than interleaving in a loop, attempt to resolve which items need to be read and do so, preferably in one operation. Then perform the delete in a separate operation. Again, all in the same transaction but don't pepper hibernate with read/delete/read/delete operations.

This is much faster and reduces the housekeeping load on Hibernate considerably. The problem went away. This occurs when you are using a secondary cache and won't occur otherwise as the load will be on the database for resolution without a secondary cache. That's another issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have had this problem,

I checked my code, there weren't any problems but when i checked my data I found out, I had two entities with the same id!

So, the `flush()` could not work, because it works one by one for batch updates and it found 2 rows. Therefore, it didn't update and threw exception, but it was my problem. I don't know if it works fine for you or not!