# Getting a org.hibernate.StaleStateException during hibernate saveOrUpdate()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have the following database table in my `PostgreSQL` database:

```
   CREATE TABLE sl_office_template
(
  layout_id integer NOT NULL,
  description character varying(500),
  time_created timestamp without time zone,
  time_updated timestamp without time zone,
  template_name character varying(65),
  site_id integer,
  template_page_type integer,
  template_theme character varying(10),
  template_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  office_template_id character varying(10),
  CONSTRAINT sl_office_template_template_id PRIMARY KEY (template_id),
  CONSTRAINT lay_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (layout_id)
      REFERENCES sl_layout (layout_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Now when I try to save any new record, I get the following exception:

```
08:36:38.366 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2525) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2478) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2805) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:114) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:260) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:180) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137) [hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:662) [spring-orm-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.saveOrUpdateTemplate(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.smartwcm.admin.navigation.controller.NavigationController.saveOrUpdateSiteTemplate(NavigationController.java:1762) [NavigationController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_31]
08:36:38.373 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.1-Final.jar:3.5.1-Final]
```

Also:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:701)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:800)
```

In the hbm.xml file, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated Mar 29, 2010 1:16:19 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.5.Beta -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.smartwcm.template.commons.to.OfficeTemplate" table="sl_office_template" catalog="public">
        <id name="templateId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="template_id" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>

        <property name="officeTemplateId" type="string">
            <column name="office_template_id"  />
        </property>

        <property name="siteId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="site_id"  />
        </property>

        <property name="templateName" type="string">
            <column name="template_name" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="layoutId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="layout_id"/>
        </property>

        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description"/>
        </property>

        <property name="timeCreated" type="java.sql.Timestamp" not-null="false" insert="true" update="false">
            <column name="time_created" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        <property name="timeUpdated" type="java.sql.Timestamp" not-null="true" insert="true" update="true">
            <column name="time_updated" not-null="true" />
        </property> 

        <property name= "templatePageType" type = "java.lang.Integer" >
            <column name="template_page_type" not-null="true" />
        </property> 

        <property name= "templateTheme" type = "string" >
            <column name="template_theme" />
        </property> 

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the corresponding pojo is:

```
public class OfficeTemplate
    {
        private Integer templateId;
        private String  officeTemplateId;
        private int     siteId;
        private String  templateName;
        private int     layoutId;
        private String      description;
        private Timestamp   timeCreated;
        private Timestamp   timeUpdated;
        private int         templatePageType;
        private String      templateTheme;
```

My saveOrUpdate() function is as follows:

```
getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(siteTemplate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Using double as a primary key is probably a bad idea.* From the postgreSQL documentation:

> The data types real and double precision are inexact,
>   variable-precision numeric types.[...]
>   Inexact means that some values cannot be converted exactly to the
>   internal format and are stored as approximations, so that **storing and
>   retrieving a value might show slight discrepancies**.

In general it sounds really dangerous to use a type with floating point representation as a key. If you do not have a really good reason to do it, you should change that type back to `int`. If you need something bigger than that, you can just go with `bigint`.

Comment: @Gregely Basco, I need that value to be double, not here exactly but in many places where I refer that field value. But is that the issue causing this exception

Comment: Needing that value is ok, just do not use it as a key. Use a sequence to generate a proper key instead. And yes, very likely that is your problem. A floating point number is never exact. When you believe it is '1.0', it can be '1.0000000001'. Hence when Hibernate  tries to update your record by searching for '1.0' it finds nothing, and then you get the error (unexpected rowcount for update: 0).

Comment: Then you need to update your question with updated schema, code, etc.

Comment: Right. I see you are using a sequence now. But you are still using the type "double"? Plus you posted that exception without the stacktrace.

Comment: I fixed the issue by creating a new integer field and using it as primary key

Comment: Good news. That was exactly my first proposal. No more issues then?

Comment: @ Gergely Bacso, the error is still not gone, looked like it was fine, but not really. I have updated the question

Comment: Ahh. No! Right, if you have now a regular ID (String as I see) your problem probably became a duplicate of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136995/821786 . If you think your problem is somehow specific and not covered by the question above, please post a new question describing your current situation and the reasons why it is a special case.