# Update table using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working under a project that is update the data's in MySQL table using Hibernate. Whenever I run the project, the exception is shown as below.

> [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual
>   row count: 0; expected: 1]

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/disableEmployeeMaster", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void disableEmployee(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    EmployeeMaster employeeMaster = new EmployeeMaster();
    try
    {
        String employeeId = request.getParameter("employeeId");
        employeeMaster.setIsDel("Y");
        mainService.disableEmployee(employeeId , employeeMaster);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
@Override
public void disableEmployee(String Id, EmployeeMaster employeeMaster) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(Id, employeeMaster);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: session.update() method parameter is an object of the model. if you have PK it will automatically update the row.

Comment: Have a look on this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124361/hibernate-delete-error-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count

Comment: According to the specification `void update(String entityName, Object object)`, I suppose the `Id` `"E02"` shouldn't be the `entityName`. Can you show us your `EmployeeMaster` entity class?

Comment: "E02" isn't entity, It's an employee ID. "employeeMaster " is Entity.

Comment: what's your primary in `EmployeeMaster`? the one that has `@Id` field?

Comment: `employeeId` is primary of my `EmployeeMaster`.

Answer (score 0):

You have't set employeeId to EmployeeMaster class object.
to update any entity needs it's primary key.
You can refer following code :

employeeMaster.setEmployeeId(employeeId);

**Controller**

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/disableEmployeeMaster", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void disableEmployee(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    EmployeeMaster employeeMaster = new EmployeeMaster();
    try
    {
        String employeeId = request.getParameter("employeeId");
        employeeMaster.setEmployeeId(employeeId);
        employeeMaster.setIsDel("Y");
        mainService.disableEmployee(employeeId , employeeMaster);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```